# Any ways to see all the songs again under the "Recently Added" tab on Apple Music for Mac?

Tags: macos, music, apple-music, music.app

I've been using Apple Music for a long time and usually navigate through my songs under the "Recently Added" tab. I was able to see all the songs arranged in the order I added them to my library, with the latest songs on the top, but now I could only see some of the songs. Are there any ways to see all the songs under "Recently Added" again?

Apple Music on iOS could show all the songs in the order of recently added under the "Albums" section, but Apple Music on Mac doesn't have that option. Or could there be some ways to realize that on Mac's Apple Music app as well?

Any kind of help is warmly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I just saw a way that can alternatively solve this problem on Apple Community Discussion:

[image]

The disadvantage of this method is that it only shows songs, rather than album grids, so I suppose it would be difficult for some listeners who prefer to play the whole album.

In the discussion, there is a user who posted a link to [Apple's Product Feedback page](https://www.apple.com/feedback/). I guess right now there's nothing we can do than this alternative method and sending feedback to Apple.